# This mod rewrite not working correctly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this

```
http://example.com/view.php?id=a1b2c3
```

I want it to look like this

```
http://example.com/v/a1b2c3
```

I am trying this

```
RewriteRule ^v/?$ view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it is not working and I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

Try this tweak:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [NE,L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`